# QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat() just kills my kernel

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

I would like to save a vector layer with Pyqgis 3, looking at [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.8/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html?highlight=filewriter#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat), and other questions on this forum, I wrote :

```
wrpath = "/home/.../joint.shp"
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(joint, wrpath, "utf-8", joint.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")

project.addMapLayer(joint)
```

But this previous just kills Python kernel, without any error message...
does someone know what I am missing ?

**EDIT** :
I use PyQgis in a standalone script. The minimal script required is :

```
##Imports

##Get and load the project instance
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2154))

grid = QgsVectorLayer(datafile + 'grid.mif', 'Grille', 'ogr')

wrpath = r"/home/edelb/Bureau/joint.shp"
print('Debug1')

#First saving way tested :
grid.selectAll()
processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT': grid, 'OUTPUT': wrpath})['OUTPUT']

#Second saving way tested :
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(grid, wrpath, "utf-8", driverName = "ESRI Shapefile")

print('Debug2')
```

At first running with Jupyter, no message was sent (just the kernel crashing), then running with PyCharm the following message :

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Rq : "Debug1" is printed, not "Debug2". Moreover, the two saving ways were tested both separately.

---

**2nd EDIT**

A very interesting fact :
I have tried to run this code inside QGIS integrated Python console. It works. But still not as a standalone way ...

Therefore, it might be useful to add here the Qgis API initialization. Before executing any code calling Qgis API, I run the following script :

```
import sys

pathlist = ['/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing',
            '/usr/share/qgis/python', '/usr/lib/qgis/plugins', '/usr/lib/python3',
            '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']  # necessary to use Processing plugin
for p in pathlist:
    sys.path.insert(0, p)

from qgis._analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.processing import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Processing initialization
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())  # needed to use native algorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

print("Initialisation : OK")
```

**Is there something to modify here to fix this segmentation fault I keep having, when I try to write/save a vector layer in a standalone script ?**

Comment: Is it the `project.addMapLayer` that crashes it? Where does `project` come from? Can you make a complete minimal example with minimal required `import` statements that shows the problem for you? Does it only happen if its a memory layer? Are you running QGIS from the command line? If so do you not even get any errors there like a segmentation fault?

Comment: @Spacedman, thx I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally discovered that I was not running native Python (the one linked to QGIS), but with Anacondas's one...
On Pycharm, you can change it quite easily. Go to `File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter`, and choose the relevant kernel.
On Jupyter (Linux), you can choose the kernel in `Kernel -> Change kernel`. If the one you want is not available in the list, then you can add it by adding a folder in `~/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/` that is a copy of another kernel folder. Just modify the folder name (e.g. 'python3(native)'), and the path to native python executable in the `kernel.json` (e.g. `/usr/bin/python3.6`).